# popup opens on the same page instead of using new window

Tags: jquery, html, popup

I'm trying out a simple popup example

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$('.example1demo').popupWindow({ 
height:500, 
width:800, 
top:50, 
left:50 
}); 
</script>
<p><a href="http://www.yahoo.com" title="yahoo.com" class="example1demo">open popup</a></p> 
</html>
```

Checked this with Firefox and chrome - instead of opening the pop-up on new window .It uses same window. How to resolve this issue and open pop-up on new window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have a look at the below code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function openWindow1()
{
var URL = "please specify your URL";
window.open(URL,"RecoverPassword","width=700,height=450");
}
</script>
<body>
<a onclick="openWindow1()" href="#">forgot password </a>
</body>
```

Hope this will help you.